# What is the main error of this code, which is used for determining date after `n` days?

Tags: c++, loops

I am a newbie to programming. Many days ago, I wrote this simple code to find a next date of a date. This code works correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Find the next date of a date.
void NextDate(int day1, int month1, int year1, int &day2, int &month2, int &year2)
{


        if ((day1 == 31) && (month1 == 12))
        {
            day2 = 1;
            month2 = 1;
            year2 = year1 + 1;
        }
        else if (((((day1 == 28) && (month1 == 2))) || ((day1 == 29) && (month1 == 2)) || (((day1 == 31) && ((month1 == 1) || (month1 == 3) || (month1 == 5) || (month1 == 7) || (month1 == 8) || (month1 == 10))))) || ((day1 == 30) && ((month1 == 4) || (month1 == 6) || (month1 == 9) || (month1 == 11))))
        {
            day2 = 1;
            month2 = month1 + 1;
            year2 = year1;
        }
        else
        {
            day2 = day1 + 1;
            month2 = month1;
            year2 = year1;
        }

}

void main()
{
    int d1, m1, y1,
        d2, m2, y2;

    // I have written a function for checking if the input is valid.
    // So, do not care about the input data.

    NextDate(d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2);

    printf("The next date of %d/%d/%d is: %d/%d/%d.", d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, t2);
    printf("\n\n---\n\n");

}
```

---

Today, I have a small task on finding the date after **n** days. So, I decide to make some changes with my old code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Find the next date of a date.
void DateAfter(int day1, int month1, int year1, int &day2, int &month2, int &year2, int n)
{

    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
    {

        if ((day1 == 31) && (month1 == 12))
        {
            day2 = 1;
            month2 = 1;
            year2 = year1 + 1;
        }
        else if (((((day1 == 28) && (month1 == 2))) || ((day1 == 29) && (month1 == 2)) || (((day1 == 31) && ((month1 == 1) || (month1 == 3) || (month1 == 5) || (month1 == 7) || (month1 == 8) || (month1 == 10))))) || ((day1 == 30) && ((month1 == 4) || (month1 == 6) || (month1 == 9) || (month1 == 11))))
        {
            day2 = 1;
            month2 = month1 + 1;
            year2 = year1;
        }
        else
        {
            day2 = day1 + 1;
            month2 = month1;
            year2 = year1;
        }
    }

}

void main()
{
    int d1, m1, y1,
        d2, m2, y2,
        n;

    DateAfter(d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2, n);

    printf("%d/%d/%d is %d days after of %d/%d/%d is.", d2, m2, y2, n, d1, m1, y1);
    printf("\n\n---\n\n");

}
```

The second code is only finding the next date.

---

Could you tell me:

- What is the problem in my inference?
- Why can't this code loop?

I know: there are many existing functions in C libraries that can help me to do this task. But, I want to write one; because, I am a newbie.

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: This looks like C++ instead of C

Comment: @4386427, Because of my programming skill; so, I am learning not-pure C.

Comment: @alk, I write them myself.

Comment: Since you use a loop why not call the original NextDate function in that loop?

Answer (score 2):

day1, month1, and year1 is used for checking in the loop but not changed, while only day2, month2, and year2 are assigned.

You should change day1, month1, and year1 within the loop and at the end (after the loop) assign them to day2, month2, and year2.

Comment: Oh, there is my mistake... Thank you very much!